# How many bytes have been read from a compressed stream?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lzma

I would like to have some progress indicator while reading data from a compressed stream in Python. I'm interested in the number of bytes read from the compressed stream, rather than how many decompressed data have been produced.

My program looks like this:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import lzma

filename = 'test.xz'
with lzma.open(filename, mode='rt') as f:
    for ln, l in enumerate(f):
        process(l)
        if ln % 1000 == 0:
            print('Read %d bytes from %s.' % (???, filename))
```

How can I get this information? I've tried `f.tell()` but it gives an error (`OSError: telling position disabled by next() call`). Even if I avoid that by explicitly using `f.readline()`, the progress reported regards the uncompressed data.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I have made some minor edits after asking and before answering. But nothing more than that.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, that all you have to do is use `f.fileno()` method to get the file descriptor associated with the compressed file. Then you can construct a file object with it, using `os.fdopen()`. The only tricky part is to set `closefd=False` so that the file descriptor is closed only once, by the lzma library.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import lzma
import os

filename = 'test.xz'
with lzma.open(filename, mode='rt') as f:
    fc = os.fdopen(f.fileno(), closefd=False)
    for ln, l in enumerate(f):
        process(l)
        if ln % 1000 == 0:
            print('Read %d bytes from %s.' % (fc.tell(), filename))
```